# Seq number for CouchDB document

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to know which database sequence number ( seqnum ) a document belongs to in Couchdb ? Like how we determine a commit hash for files in git ?

I am looking for some kind of a _field which is already present or can be determined.

Please help. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [changes feed](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/1536-feature_add-docs/changes.html) to connect a seqnum to a specific document if you know the seqnum ahead of time.

```
GET /database/_changes?since=<seqnum - 1>&limit=1
```

It will return you just a single result, and it will have the changed document's ID, as well as whatever changes were made during that write operation.

Comment: excellent ! .. thank you. I would like to tweak your answer to this for my reference: GET /database/_changes?filter=_doc_ids&since=now&descending=true&limit=1&doc_ids=["<doc_id"]